# Saving a numpy array on disk

Tags: python

I have a very large size multi-dimensional numpy array. I want to save it so as to save time. I am using `pickle` for that purpose.

```
pickle.dump( arrTotal, open( "arrTotal.p", "wb" ) )
```

But I am getting `Memory Error` when I try to save it this way. Is there some other way I can do it without causing memory error?

Answer (score 2):

Pickle is almost certainly not an ideal format for saving numpy data...

I'd recommend trying something like [`numpy.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) or [`numpy.savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried using numpy.savez. But, still I am getting the same Memory Error